# Fixed voltage drop (current and temperature independent)

Tags: voltage-reference, shunt, voltage

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6d4hq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there a clever way to create a fixed voltage drop say 2V that is not affected by current or temperature?
Voltage stability should stay within 1-3%(5% at most) over -40...60C.
Specified drop should be at few hundred microamps and it should endure atleast 50mA per LED.

As you can see a 2V zener voltage varies greatly due to current and temperature:
[image]

The problem is that I need to adjust the brightness of 24V LED-s. I have 24V supply voltage and want to adjust LED voltage from 2 to 15V using DCDC converter. Very few converters have such a large adjustment range, so I need to chop off extra 2V from DCDC output to make the LED really dim. Individual LED-s are controlled by NPN transistors in common emitter mode.

Comment: Search programmable zener on this site

Comment: Post your current circuit schematic and explain exactly where you wish to "lose" 2 volts.

Comment: XY problem? Exactly what are these 'LED's that can work from 2V to 15V?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, but to address your X as it stands, consider a TLV431 driving a PNP transistor.

Comment: Normal dimming scheme is to use PWM (pulse-width modulation) at full voltage.

Comment: I taught about PWM but figured it could create a lot of noise. So I figured I would need some LC filter also(no?), and would make things complicated

Comment: If you want LED *brightness* control, then you should think in terms of average *current*, not voltage.

Comment: Why do you need this level of precision? Just adjust your DC/DC converters to compensate. Do they provide 1% accuracy...if not, there is no point in asking for that.

Comment: I edited post, its stability not precision im after. The voltage vs brightness adjustment is not linear, it gets extremely sensitive at small voltages and I need to be able to dim LEDs to almost not visible intensity (for night vision goggles). If I would to use PWM the Duty will have to be smaller than 1% (maybe 0.1%) at dim settings and 100% at bright settings, so very extreme requirements

Comment: I think Im going with the PWM option, now I will have to learn about filtering EMI :)

Comment: 0.1% PWM duty is not extreme. 0.00001% PWM duty is not extreme. These are trivially achievable with a microcontroller.